# How do you solve this inequality? $\frac{1}{(n+1)4^{n+1}} < .001 $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, lambert-w

$$\frac{1}{(n+1)4^{n+1}} < .001 $$

becomes

$$ 1000 < (n+1)4^{n+1}$$

Where do you go from here?
Am I supposed to plug in a table of values for n?

n=1:  1000 < 32

n=2:  1000 < 192

n=3:  1000 < 1024

So, n=3 satisfies the inequality.

But, I've been told the answer is $n>3$

Comment: My guess is that this will involve the Lambert $\mathrm{W}$-function. By the way you forgot the trivial case, in which $n+1\lt 0$.

Comment: You are right, the positive integer solutions are all $n\ge 3$.

Comment: Are you supposed to solve that inequality over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: For $\frac{1}{(n+1)4^{n+1}}\lt \epsilon$, we can get a ballpark estimate by solving $\frac{1}{4^{n+1}}\lt \epsilon$ and making a small adjustment. For a good approximation of where we get equality, use a numerical method.

Comment: Well, it's part of a Alternating Series Error problem.  So, n starts at 1 in the sigma notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we're solving the inequality over $\mathbb{N}$, we may use induction. First, one can already sense that there exists some $N$ such that the inequality, $$1000\lt(n+1)4^{n+1},\tag1$$ will be true for all $n\geqslant N$. A reasonable guess for such $N$ is, as you found, $N=3$. Now suppose that $(1)$ is true. Then $$
\begin{align}
1000\lt(n+1)4^{n+1}
& \implies
1000\lt(n+2)4^{n+1}\lt (n+2)4^{n+1}\cdot 4 \\
&\implies 1000\lt(n+2) 4^{n+2}.
\end{align}$$
Hence by induction, $(1)$ holds for all $n\geqslant3$.

Answer (score 0):

To solve for $n$, I must first start with $1000=(n+1)4^{n+1}$

The solution for $n$ may be found in terms of the Lambert W function (or product log), and it is:

$$n=\frac{W(1000\ln(4))}{\ln(4)}-1$$

Where $W(x)$ is the Lambert W function.

In other words, to solve the inequality, it is simply $n>\frac{W(1000\ln(4))}{\ln(4)}-1\approx2.985509972\approx3$

So there you have it.